# Getting descendants using LINQ to XML

Tags: linq-to-xml

I want to use LINQ to XML to query XML document looking like this

```
<root>
     <data>
        <_0>
            <id>123</id>
            <status>complete</status>
            <datesubmitted>2014-07-07 10:35:45</datesubmitted>
            <question1>10</question1>
            <question2>Yes</question2>
            <question3></question3>
        </_0>
        <_1>
            <id>456</id>
            <status>complete</status>
            <datesubmitted>2014-07-07 11:05:45</datesubmitted>
            <question1>10</question1>
            <question2>Yes</question2>
            <question3></question3>
        </_1>
        <_2>
            <id>789</id>
            <status>complete</status>
            <datesubmitted>2014-07-07 12:15:45</datesubmitted>
            <question1>10</question1>
            <question2>Yes</question2>
            <question3></question3>
        </_2>
    </data>
    </root>
```

I was able to get to element "data" using

```
               IEnumerable<XElement> ldata =
                    from el in root.Elements("data")
                    select el;
```

But I having trouble to come up with next query to get  descendants  in order later to loop though to populate my objects. Thank you

Comment: Martin, thank you for the fast reply. I forgot to include additional 3 nodes as "questions". So, I'm wondering is any way I can extract those using LIKE statement instead of hard coding

Comment: question1 = (string)child.Element("question1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Elements()`:

```
var data = from child in root.Elements("data").Elements() select new {
  id = (int)child.Element("id"),
  status = (string)child.Element("status"),
  date = (string)child.Element("datesubmitted")
};
```

Comment: Martin, thank you for the fast reply. I forgot to include additional 3 nodes as "questions". So, I'm wondering is any way I can extract those using something LIKE statement instead of hard coding question1 = (string)child.Element("question1"), question2 = (string)child.Element("question2") and so on

Comment: Well if you want to populate three properties `question1`, `question2`, `question3` then hard coding that seems like the correct approach. And the whole XML format is not really a good design with an index in element names, normally you would have a wrapper element `<questions><question>..</question><question>..</question></questions>`. If you don't need any distinct properties but for instance only a string property with all those `questionX` elements then you could use `questions = string.Join(",", child.Elements().Where(q => q.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("question")).Select(e => e.Value))`.